# Traveling in the umbra of a solar eclipse

Tags: velocity, speed, eclipse

On August 21 this year, parts of the United States will experience a total solar eclipse, as many of you probably know. Say that I am in an airplane at the center of the umbra of the moon when it touches the coast of Oregon. How fast must I travel to remain in the center as the eclipse moves across the United States? Answers may be either the average velocity or an equation describing the instantaneous velocity. The later might be the most interesting if the speed is not constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This website from NASA](https://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2006/faq.php) states that eclipse shadows move at 1,100 mph near the equator and 5,000 mph near the poles (respectively 1,800 kph and 8,000 kph).  Current passenger jets don't move that fast; you'd have to be on board a Concorde or a military jet to reach even the lowest speeds in that range, and the fastest manned plane ever (the North American X-15) at 4,500 mph (7,200 kph) would still fall short of the polar speeds of the eclipse shadow.

[This website](http://eclipse2017.org/blog/2016/11/27/how-fast-is-the-shadow-moving-across-the-us-during-the-eclipse/) specifically states that the eclipse speed in western Oregon will be almost 3000 mph.

Going into calculations of the speed of eclipse shadows is not just the actual speed of the moon crossing in front of the sun relative to the earth, but also the earth's motion around the sun, the speed of the earth's rotation, and changes in speed over an eclipse path due to the effects of projecting onto a sphere.

Comment: "in front of the **sun** relative to the earth"

Comment: My hypothetical airplane ride was to avoid issues with navigating terrain while remaining relatively close to the earth's surface.

Comment: @Code-Guru, fixed it thanks.  Do you have edit privileges yet?  You could edit it yourself.

Comment: No. I do not have enough rep for such a small edit. Suggested edits must change a minimum of 10 characters. Frustrating since I can edit freely on other SE sites.